# Message to report the number of days worked

Tags: vba, excel

I used below code to be informed if anyone registered in the payroll that he worked less than 30 days. It works great but the issue I have is that the message given contains the name of the employee eg. `Nabil Amer worked H days`.

Here I want the message to define the number of days instead of the letter "H"

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim EmpName As String
    Dim RowNrNumeric As Long
    Dim RowNrString As String
    Dim CloumnEmpName As String
    Dim CloumnNameRemStatus As String
    Dim RemStatus As String
    Dim Daysworked As String

    Sheets("Master Payroll").Select
    CloumnEmpName = "C"
    CloumnNameRemStatus = "K"
    Daysworked = "H"
    RowNrNumeric = 2
    RowNrString = RowNrNumeric
    EmpName = Range(CloumnEmpName + RowNrString).Value
    DueDate = Range(CloumnNameDate + RowNrString).Value
    RemStatus = Range(CloumnNameRemStatus + RowNrString).Value

    Do While EmpName <> ""
        If Cells(RowNrNumeric, 8).Value < 30 _
        And Not IsEmpty(Cells(RowNrNumeric, 2)) Then
            MsgBox "WARNING: " + EmpName + " worked for " + Daysworked + " Days "
            Range(Daysworked + RowNrString).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Range(Daysworked + RowNrString).Select
        End If

        RowNrNumeric = RowNrNumeric + 1
        RowNrString = RowNrNumeric
        EmpName = Range(CloumnEmpName + RowNrString).Value
        RemStatus = Range(CloumnNameRemStatus + RowNrString).Value
    Loop
End Sub
```

**Screen shot:**

[image: Sample Worksheet]

Comment: sorry I want to add also image to make myself more clear  but I system not allowed me to do so.

Comment: Upload the image in any free image hosting site (e.g imgur.com) and paste the link in your question.

Comment: thanks I will.  http://i.imgur.com/72KvW7L.png?1

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
MsgBox "WARNING: " + EmpName + " worked for " + Daysworked + " Days "
```

To this:

```
MsgBox "WARNING: " + EmpName + " worked for " & Range(Daysworked & RowNrNumeric).Value & " Days "
```